# Error : issue while using createChannel command

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I've been following the tutorial for the Hyperledger Fabric development
but i have this error message while trying the command `./network.sh createChannel`:

```
Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: orderer client failed to connect to localhost:7050: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp [::1]:7050: connectex: Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée."
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

The French part means that no connection can be established cause the targeted computer has refused it.

After searching a bit there might be an issue with the ports or ip addresses but not sure.

My logs for the different components :

Orderer service :

```
2020-05-27 09:13:16.388 UTC [localconfig] completeInitialization -> WARN 001 General.GenesisFile should be replaced by General.BootstrapFile
2020-05-27 09:13:16.389 UTC [localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 Kafka.Version unset, setting to 0.10.2.0
2020-05-27 09:13:16.389 UTC [orderer.common.server] prettyPrintStruct -> INFO 003 Orderer config values:
        General.ListenAddress = "0.0.0.0"
        General.ListenPort = 7050
        General.TLS.Enabled = true
        General.TLS.PrivateKey = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key"
        General.TLS.Certificate = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt"
        General.TLS.RootCAs = [/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
        General.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
        General.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
        General.Cluster.ListenAddress = ""
        General.Cluster.ListenPort = 0
        General.Cluster.ServerCertificate = ""
        General.Cluster.ServerPrivateKey = ""
        General.Cluster.ClientCertificate = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt"
        General.Cluster.ClientPrivateKey = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key"
        General.Cluster.RootCAs = [/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
        General.Cluster.DialTimeout = 5s
        General.Cluster.RPCTimeout = 7s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationBufferSize = 20971520
        General.Cluster.ReplicationPullTimeout = 5s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationRetryTimeout = 5s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationBackgroundRefreshInterval = 5m0s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationMaxRetries = 12
        General.Cluster.SendBufferSize = 10
        General.Cluster.CertExpirationWarningThreshold = 168h0m0s
        General.Cluster.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
        General.Keepalive.ServerMinInterval = 1m0s
        General.Keepalive.ServerInterval = 2h0m0s
        General.Keepalive.ServerTimeout = 20s
        General.ConnectionTimeout = 0s
        General.GenesisMethod = "file"
        General.GenesisFile = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block"
        General.BootstrapMethod = "file"
        General.BootstrapFile = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block"
        General.Profile.Enabled = false
        General.Profile.Address = "0.0.0.0:6060"
        General.LocalMSPDir = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp"
        General.LocalMSPID = "OrdererMSP"
        General.BCCSP.ProviderName = "SW"
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.SecLevel = 256
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.HashFamily = "SHA2"
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.Ephemeral = true
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.FileKeystore.KeyStorePath = ""
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.DummyKeystore =
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.InmemKeystore =
        General.Authentication.TimeWindow = 15m0s
        General.Authentication.NoExpirationChecks = false
        FileLedger.Location = "/var/hyperledger/production/orderer"
        FileLedger.Prefix = "hyperledger-fabric-ordererledger"
        Kafka.Retry.ShortInterval = 5s
        Kafka.Retry.ShortTotal = 10m0s
        Kafka.Retry.LongInterval = 5m0s
        Kafka.Retry.LongTotal = 12h0m0s
        Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.DialTimeout = 10s
        Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.ReadTimeout = 10s
        Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.WriteTimeout = 10s
        Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryMax = 3
        Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryBackoff = 250ms
        Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryMax = 3
        Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryBackoff = 100ms
        Kafka.Retry.Consumer.RetryBackoff = 2s
        Kafka.Verbose = true
        Kafka.Version = 0.10.2.0
        Kafka.TLS.Enabled = false
        Kafka.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
        Kafka.TLS.Certificate = ""
        Kafka.TLS.RootCAs = []
        Kafka.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
        Kafka.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
        Kafka.SASLPlain.Enabled = false
        Kafka.SASLPlain.User = ""
        Kafka.SASLPlain.Password = ""
        Kafka.Topic.ReplicationFactor = 1
        Debug.BroadcastTraceDir = ""
        Debug.DeliverTraceDir = ""
        Consensus = map[SnapDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/snapshot WALDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal]
        Operations.ListenAddress = "127.0.0.1:8443"
        Operations.TLS.Enabled = false
        Operations.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
        Operations.TLS.Certificate = ""
        Operations.TLS.RootCAs = []
        Operations.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
        Operations.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
        Metrics.Provider = "disabled"
        Metrics.Statsd.Network = "udp"
        Metrics.Statsd.Address = "127.0.0.1:8125"
        Metrics.Statsd.WriteInterval = 30s
        Metrics.Statsd.Prefix = ""
2020-05-27 09:13:16.400 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 004 Failed loading ClientOU certificate at [/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.example.com-cert.pem: open /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.400 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 005 Failed loading PeerOU certificate at [/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.example.com-cert.pem: open /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.400 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 006 Failed loading AdminOU certificate at [/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.example.com-cert.pem: open /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.400 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 007 Failed loading OrdererOU certificate at [/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.example.com-cert.pem: open /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.434 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO 008 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
2020-05-27 09:13:16.441 UTC [fsblkstorage] NewProvider -> INFO 009 Creating new file ledger directory at /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/chains
2020-05-27 09:13:16.464 UTC [orderer.common.server] extractSysChanLastConfig -> INFO 00a Bootstrapping because no existing channels
2020-05-27 09:13:16.483 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> INFO 00b Setting up cluster for orderer type etcdraft
2020-05-27 09:13:16.490 UTC [orderer.common.server] reuseListener -> INFO 00c Cluster listener is not configured, defaulting to use the general listener on port 7050
2020-05-27 09:13:16.490 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 00d Getting block information from block storage
2020-05-27 09:13:16.529 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] HandleChain -> INFO 00e EvictionSuspicion not set, defaulting to 10m0s
2020-05-27 09:13:16.530 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] createOrReadWAL -> INFO 00f No WAL data found, creating new WAL at path '/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal/system-channel' channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:16.536 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] Initialize -> INFO 010 Starting system channel 'system-channel' with genesis block hash 22c93e29c38e9681f960d390fda12c72869fc9ebfebf0a6d1c15f60198b13119 and orderer type etcdraft
2020-05-27 09:13:16.537 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] Start -> INFO 011 Starting Raft node channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:16.537 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] Configure -> INFO 012 Entering, channel: system-channel, nodes: []
2020-05-27 09:13:16.537 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] Configure -> INFO 013 Exiting
2020-05-27 09:13:16.537 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] start -> INFO 014 Starting raft node as part of a new channel channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:16.537 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomeFollower -> INFO 015 1 became follower at term 0 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:16.538 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] newRaft -> INFO 016 newRaft 1 [peers: [], term: 0, commit: 0, applied: 0, lastindex: 0, lastterm: 0] channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:16.538 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomeFollower -> INFO 017 1 became follower at term 1 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:16.538 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> INFO 018 Starting orderer:
 Version: 2.1.0
 Commit SHA: 1bdf975
 Go version: go1.14.1
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2020-05-27 09:13:16.538 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> INFO 019 Beginning to serve requests
2020-05-27 09:13:16.538 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 01a This node is picked to start campaign channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:16.539 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] apply -> INFO 01b Applied config change to add node 1, current nodes in channel: [1] channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:17.539 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] Step -> INFO 01c 1 is starting a new election at term 1 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:17.540 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomePreCandidate -> INFO 01d 1 became pre-candidate at term 1 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:17.540 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> INFO 01e 1 received MsgPreVoteResp from 1 at term 1 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:17.540 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomeCandidate -> INFO 01f 1 became candidate at term 2 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:17.541 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> INFO 020 1 received MsgVoteResp from 1 at term 2 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:17.541 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomeLeader -> INFO 021 1 became leader at term 2 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:17.541 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 022 raft.node: 1 elected leader 1 at term 2 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:17.542 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 023 Leader 1 is present, quit campaign channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:17.543 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 024 Raft leader changed: 0 -> 1 channel=system-channel node=1
2020-05-27 09:13:17.543 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 025 Start accepting requests as Raft leader at block [0] channel=system-channel node=1
```

Peer 1 :

```
2020-05-27 09:13:16.435 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 001 Failed loading ClientOU certificate at [/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.435 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 002 Failed loading PeerOU certificate at [/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.435 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 003 Failed loading AdminOU certificate at [/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.436 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 004 Failed loading OrdererOU certificate at [/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.441 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 005 Starting peer:
 Version: 2.1.0
 Commit SHA: 1bdf975
 Go version: go1.14.1
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Chaincode:
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger
2020-05-27 09:13:16.442 UTC [peer] getLocalAddress -> INFO 006 Auto-detected peer address: 172.18.0.3:7051
2020-05-27 09:13:16.442 UTC [peer] getLocalAddress -> INFO 007 Returning peer0.org1.example.com:7051
2020-05-27 09:13:16.469 UTC [nodeCmd] initGrpcSemaphores -> INFO 008 concurrency limit for endorser service is 2500
2020-05-27 09:13:16.470 UTC [nodeCmd] initGrpcSemaphores -> INFO 009 concurrency limit for deliver service is 2500
2020-05-27 09:13:16.470 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 00a Starting peer with TLS enabled
2020-05-27 09:13:16.500 UTC [ledgermgmt] NewLedgerMgr -> INFO 00b Initializing LedgerMgr
2020-05-27 09:13:16.513 UTC [leveldbhelper] openDBAndCheckFormat -> INFO 00c DB is empty Setting db format as 2.0
2020-05-27 09:13:16.514 UTC [fsblkstorage] NewProvider -> INFO 00d Creating new file ledger directory at /var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/chains
2020-05-27 09:13:16.521 UTC [leveldbhelper] openDBAndCheckFormat -> INFO 00e DB is empty Setting db format as 2.0
2020-05-27 09:13:16.535 UTC [leveldbhelper] openDBAndCheckFormat -> INFO 00f DB is empty Setting db format as 2.0
2020-05-27 09:13:16.536 UTC [ledgermgmt] NewLedgerMgr -> INFO 010 Initialized LedgerMgr
2020-05-27 09:13:16.547 UTC [gossip.service] New -> INFO 011 Initialize gossip with endpoint peer0.org1.example.com:7051
2020-05-27 09:13:16.549 UTC [gossip.gossip] New -> INFO 012 Creating gossip service with self membership of Endpoint: peer0.org1.example.com:7051, InternalEndpoint: peer0.org1.example.com:7051, PKI-ID: 58df3c0a908cbbd073a6b4138ef676c652aaab118fb99179d7304206f63a0207, Metadata:
2020-05-27 09:13:16.550 UTC [lifecycle] InitializeLocalChaincodes -> INFO 013 Initialized lifecycle cache with 0 already installed chaincodes
2020-05-27 09:13:16.550 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 014 Entering computeChaincodeEndpoint with peerHostname: peer0.org1.example.com
2020-05-27 09:13:16.550 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 015 Exit with ccEndpoint: peer0.org1.example.com:7052
2020-05-27 09:13:16.550 UTC [gossip.gossip] start -> INFO 016 Gossip instance peer0.org1.example.com:7051 started
2020-05-27 09:13:16.560 UTC [sccapi] DeploySysCC -> INFO 017 deploying system chaincode 'lscc'
2020-05-27 09:13:16.560 UTC [sccapi] DeploySysCC -> INFO 018 deploying system chaincode 'cscc'
2020-05-27 09:13:16.560 UTC [sccapi] DeploySysCC -> INFO 019 deploying system chaincode 'qscc'
2020-05-27 09:13:16.560 UTC [sccapi] DeploySysCC -> INFO 01a deploying system chaincode '_lifecycle'
2020-05-27 09:13:16.560 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 01b Deployed system chaincodes
2020-05-27 09:13:16.560 UTC [discovery] NewService -> INFO 01c Created with config TLS: true, authCacheMaxSize: 1000, authCachePurgeRatio: 0.750000
2020-05-27 09:13:16.560 UTC [nodeCmd] registerDiscoveryService -> INFO 01d Discovery service activated
2020-05-27 09:13:16.560 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 01e Starting peer with ID=[peer0.org1.example.com], network ID=[dev], address=[peer0.org1.example.com:7051]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.560 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 01f Started peer with ID=[peer0.org1.example.com], network ID=[dev], address=[peer0.org1.example.com:7051]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.560 UTC [kvledger] LoadPreResetHeight -> INFO 020 Loading prereset height from path [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.561 UTC [fsblkstorage] preResetHtFiles -> INFO 021 No active channels passed
2020-05-27 09:13:16.561 UTC [nodeCmd] func6 -> INFO 022 Starting profiling server with listenAddress = 0.0.0.0:6060
```

Peer 2 :

```
2020-05-27 09:13:16.409 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 001 Failed loading ClientOU certificate at [/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.410 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 002 Failed loading PeerOU certificate at [/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.410 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 003 Failed loading AdminOU certificate at [/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.410 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 004 Failed loading OrdererOU certificate at [/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/cacerts\ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.420 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 005 Starting peer:
 Version: 2.1.0
 Commit SHA: 1bdf975
 Go version: go1.14.1
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Chaincode:
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger
2020-05-27 09:13:16.421 UTC [peer] getLocalAddress -> INFO 006 Auto-detected peer address: 172.18.0.2:9051
2020-05-27 09:13:16.421 UTC [peer] getLocalAddress -> INFO 007 Returning peer0.org2.example.com:9051
2020-05-27 09:13:16.433 UTC [nodeCmd] initGrpcSemaphores -> INFO 008 concurrency limit for endorser service is 2500
2020-05-27 09:13:16.434 UTC [nodeCmd] initGrpcSemaphores -> INFO 009 concurrency limit for deliver service is 2500
2020-05-27 09:13:16.434 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 00a Starting peer with TLS enabled
2020-05-27 09:13:16.472 UTC [ledgermgmt] NewLedgerMgr -> INFO 00b Initializing LedgerMgr
2020-05-27 09:13:16.492 UTC [leveldbhelper] openDBAndCheckFormat -> INFO 00c DB is empty Setting db format as 2.0
2020-05-27 09:13:16.493 UTC [fsblkstorage] NewProvider -> INFO 00d Creating new file ledger directory at /var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/chains
2020-05-27 09:13:16.501 UTC [leveldbhelper] openDBAndCheckFormat -> INFO 00e DB is empty Setting db format as 2.0
2020-05-27 09:13:16.528 UTC [leveldbhelper] openDBAndCheckFormat -> INFO 00f DB is empty Setting db format as 2.0
2020-05-27 09:13:16.528 UTC [ledgermgmt] NewLedgerMgr -> INFO 010 Initialized LedgerMgr
2020-05-27 09:13:16.542 UTC [gossip.service] New -> INFO 011 Initialize gossip with endpoint peer0.org2.example.com:9051
2020-05-27 09:13:16.547 UTC [gossip.gossip] New -> INFO 012 Creating gossip service with self membership of Endpoint: peer0.org2.example.com:9051, InternalEndpoint: peer0.org2.example.com:9051, PKI-ID: c7429efa7a899a8b3644235bc56251ffbfb45fe3f55fc0a4d199fd03b1521df4, Metadata:
2020-05-27 09:13:16.547 UTC [lifecycle] InitializeLocalChaincodes -> INFO 013 Initialized lifecycle cache with 0 already installed chaincodes
2020-05-27 09:13:16.548 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 014 Entering computeChaincodeEndpoint with peerHostname: peer0.org2.example.com
2020-05-27 09:13:16.548 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 015 Exit with ccEndpoint: peer0.org2.example.com:9052
2020-05-27 09:13:16.549 UTC [gossip.gossip] start -> INFO 016 Gossip instance peer0.org2.example.com:9051 started
2020-05-27 09:13:16.555 UTC [sccapi] DeploySysCC -> INFO 017 deploying system chaincode 'lscc'
2020-05-27 09:13:16.558 UTC [sccapi] DeploySysCC -> INFO 018 deploying system chaincode 'cscc'
2020-05-27 09:13:16.558 UTC [sccapi] DeploySysCC -> INFO 019 deploying system chaincode 'qscc'
2020-05-27 09:13:16.559 UTC [sccapi] DeploySysCC -> INFO 01a deploying system chaincode '_lifecycle'
2020-05-27 09:13:16.559 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 01b Deployed system chaincodes
2020-05-27 09:13:16.559 UTC [discovery] NewService -> INFO 01c Created with config TLS: true, authCacheMaxSize: 1000, authCachePurgeRatio: 0.750000
2020-05-27 09:13:16.559 UTC [nodeCmd] registerDiscoveryService -> INFO 01d Discovery service activated
2020-05-27 09:13:16.559 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 01e Starting peer with ID=[peer0.org2.example.com], network ID=[dev], address=[peer0.org2.example.com:9051]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.559 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 01f Started peer with ID=[peer0.org2.example.com], network ID=[dev], address=[peer0.org2.example.com:9051]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.559 UTC [kvledger] LoadPreResetHeight -> INFO 020 Loading prereset height from path [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains]
2020-05-27 09:13:16.559 UTC [fsblkstorage] preResetHtFiles -> INFO 021 No active channels passed
2020-05-27 09:13:16.559 UTC [nodeCmd] func6 -> INFO 022 Starting profiling server with listenAddress = 0.0.0.0:6060
```

There are also several warnings but don't really know their meaning.

I've tried to relaunch docker as admin , also tried to relaunch the network.

Comment: The problem is with loading msp, tls cert files, your log shows that no such file exists. Also path to the cert files are not correctly recognized. On what OS (environment) are you trying to run the tutorial.

Comment: Hi, i'm on windows 10.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this problem?